# Saved View with a timestamp expression

Tags: sql

Is there a standard for how data is represented in a Saved View where a timestamp/voltatile expression is used? For example, let's say I have the SQL query:

```
SELECT person_id, name, NOW() as now FROM table
```

The `NOW()` function will have a different value every time it is run. When saving the above to a view, is the data stored as:

```
person_id          name             now
1                  Bob              2020-01-01T01:01:01
2                  Billy            2020-01-01T01:01:01
3                  Barbara          2020-01-01T01:01:01
```

Or is it stored as:

```
person_id          name             now
1                  Bob              =NOW()
2                  Billy            =NOW()
3                  Barbara          =NOW()
```

Or, is it dependent on the database implementation and there is no standard?

Comment: A view is not "saved", it's just a Select. Why don't you simply try it?

Comment: @dnoeth yes I tried a table and a view and the table is stored permanently and the view is calculated on-demand. What about a materialized view then?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh for me it's more a conceptual question, but for testing it I was using mysql (which doesn't have a materialized view)

Comment: You store values, e.g. a timestamp, in a table (using INSERT/UPDATE). When you SELECT, you will get the value as it was stored. You can also select a function (e.g. NOW()), and you'll get the current timestamp. A view is just a pre-defined select. A materialized view is a optimization trick where the view-select is prepared and stored for faster access - but you will still get the result as the select.

Comment: @jarlh could you please clarify the part about `A materialized view is a optimization trick where the view-select is prepared and stored for faster access`. Isn't a view then more like a saved query and a materialized view more like a table (with some maintenance done behind the scenes?)

Comment: @David542 "Isn't a view then more like a saved query and a materialized view more like a table (with some maintenance done behind the scenes?)" - No, a view is just a predefined SELECT query on a specified table.
A materialized view is the exact same query but instead of requesting it everytime, it is cached for faster access.

Comment: @dmuensterer cached = saved to some sort of storage, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see how this would be misleading.  However, a view does not "store" data (except for materialized views, which are a different store).

A view is a query which is *substituted* into the query where it is used.  Admittedly, it *could* be parsed in advance, saving a small amount of effort.

However, a function such as `now()` is called when a query is *executed*.  So, the value you will see is the value when the query is run.

This is actually a *little* confusing, because the function `now()` is not called for every row.  Instead, it is evaluated once when the query starts execution.  However, the query in question is the query that *uses* the view, not the command that *creates* the view.

Answer (score 1):

Now() is only a function, which will be run at insertion time.

so the result will  be

```
person_id          name             now
1                  Bob              2020-01-01 01:01:01
2                  Billy            2020-01-01 01:01:01
3                  Barbara          2020-01-01 01:01:01
```

Comment: I see, so how is the `now()` function stored then? And I assume a view then is different than `CREATE TABLE AS...` where the values are stored permanently?

Comment: it is build in, but you can add your own functions by plugin